# The time of waiting at a bank.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a bank. The time expressed in minutes that every customer took to finish his job at the bank is given(the numbers are distributed with exponential distribution):

$7.4,\ 7.5,\ 8.5,\ 29.2,\ 5.5,\ 21.6,\ 4.3,\ 8.1,\ 5.3,\ 1.7$

(the customers are served one by one)

1. You come to the bank and there is a customer that is there for $5$ minutes. What is the probability that you will have to wait for him to finish for at least another $3$ minutes.

   The estimator for exponential distribution is $\lambda = \frac{1}{\text{avg}} = \frac{1}{10}$
   $$F(x>8;\frac{1}{10}) = 1 - F(5<x<8;\frac{1}{10}) = 1 - (F(8;\frac{1}{10}) - F(5;\frac{1}{10})) = 1 - (1 - e^{-\frac{4}{5}}) + (1 - e^{\frac{1}{2}})$$I know I am wrong somewhere and I am asking you to help me with this.
2. At one moment at the bank arrive $35$ customers. What is the probability that they will finish their job after $45$ minutes

Answer (score 1):

For (a) you are wrong because $1 - F(5<x<8;\frac{1}{10})$ gives you the probability that either $x\leq 3$ or $x\geq 8$. You have to write:
$$
P(x\geq 8|x\geq 5)=\frac{P(x\geq 8,x\geq 5)}{P(x\geq 5)}=\frac{P(x\geq 8)}{P(x\geq 5)}=P(x\geq 3)
$$
Indeed the exponential distribution is memoryless which is:
$$
P(x\geq a+b|x\geq a)=P(x\geq b).
$$
For (b), You have to define $X_i$, the random variable for the time took for each person to finish his job. Then $S=\sum_{i=1}^{i=35} X_i$ is the random variable representing the total time for all of them. The event that you are interested in has the corresponding probability:
$$
P(\sum_{i=1}^{i=35}X_i>45)
$$
This is Hypoexponential distribution which you can find here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution